Cannot find VirtualNetwork when deploying an app service in different resource group in Bicep
I'm getting an error "Cannot find VirtualNetwork with name vnet-name". The vnet is in a different resource group than the web app.
var subnetName = 'subnetName'
var linuxVersion = 'node|20-lts'

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: '${webAppPrefix}${name}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: webAppPlan.id
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vnet-name' , subnetName)
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxVersion  
    }
  }
}


Try using virtualNetworkSubnetId: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vnet-name', subnetName) instead of what you mentioned in query @Lee

@VinayB I tried that (and changed my query above) but still got the same error.

Where is the virtual network? Same resource group or somewhere else?

@D1__1...ahhh. I hadn't thought of that. The vnet is in a different resource group.

Because the existing virtual network is in a different resource group, you need to pass the name of the resource group that it is in to the resourceId function.
virtualNetworkSubnetId: resourceId('resourceGroupName', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vnet-name', 'subnet-name')

Alternatively, use the existing keyword to work with your existing resources.
resource existingVirtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-11-01' existing = {
  name: 'vnet-name'
  scope: resourceGroup('resourceGroupName')
}

resource existingSubnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2023-11-01' existing = {
  name: 'subnetName'
  parent: existingVirtualNetwork
}

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: 'appservice-deployment'
  location: location
  properties: {
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: existingSubnet.id
    ...
  }
}


Because the Virtual Network is in a different Resource Group as the app service, the Resource Group must be explicitly specified as follows:
virtualNetworkSubnetId: resourceId('vnet-resource-group-name', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets','vnet-name', 'subnet-name')

it is well documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource
